# Mariadb Foreign key on remote table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB support foreign keys reference tables only with InnoDB engine.
Is there a workaroud to use a remote (engine=CONNECT) table?

Comment: A foreign key to a remote table would be highly inefficient as it could not use indexes to check if a value existed in the remote table.

Comment: So, a work around should be insert a trigger on the remote table to populate a local one. However, about efficiency, in my case the remote table is on the same machine.

Comment: No matter where the remote table is located! If you cannot use indexes for fast lookups for checking for existing values, then the lookup is just too expensive. If the remote table is on the same machine, consider bringing it within the same mysql instance and no need to use connect engine any more!

Comment: Obvious that if I could put the remote table on the same db I wouldn't have this problem.
I put a trigger on the remote DB.